# iOS 8 Google Maps SDK myLocation icon bubble graphical glitch

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I am learning about the Google Maps SDK and getting to know Swift, and when I create a mapview centered on my location using `myLocation = true`, the location bubble shows up, but it appears with a square mask around it like this

[image]

I am not performing any operation on the location indicator, at least not intentionally.

Has anyone ran into this issue before?

Comment: Which Google Maps SDK version you are using? Can you also post the code you use to show the blue icon?

Comment: I am using Google Maps 1.9.1 and the code I am using to show my location is `(self.view as GMSMapView).myLocationEnabled = true`

Comment: Im experiencing the exact same problem. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Nope, but a friend counseled me to use MapKit instead.  His logic, which I see, is that when users use an iOS app, and a map is embedded, they expect to see a MapKit map, because those maps conform to iOS's visual style. If you really need guidance in your app, then GMaps is the way to go though.

Answer (score 12):

This is a known issue when running the Simulator. It works correctly on a real device. It's marked as WontFix on the issue tracker.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5113

Answer (score 2):

Just like zhm said.
It is a known problem with Xcode simulator and works fine on the real iOS device.
I'm adding screenshots of the difference:

[image: From Simulator]

[image: From iPhone]